# Should I use a delegate method or UINotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

So right now I have a `rootViewController` which has a `UIPageViewController` as its only subview, `rootViewController` is basically a wrapper class for `UIPageViewController`. Now I want to disable scroll for the `UIPageViewController` from `ViewControllerA` (which is owned by `rootViewController`).

Right now I have implemented a delegate method (created by `ViewControllerA`) for the `rootViewController` which tells the `UIPageViewController` it has to stop scrolling depending on information given by `ViewControllerA`. But for the `ViewControllerA` to be able to call the delegate method implemented by `rootViewController` would require the `rootViewController` to be an instance variable of `ViewControllerA`.

Would this be the best practice? Would using `NSNotificationCenter` be a better choice? Or are none of these methods the best choice?

Comment: Usually Notification Center is used when you want that more than one object is informed about what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be to use a delegate or a callback property:

```
final class ViewControllerA: UIViewController
{
    var callback: (ViewControllerA -> ())?

    func somethingHappened()
    {
        callback?(self)
    }
}
```

If you're using this style, be sure to avoid a reference cycle:

```
let viewControllerA = ViewControllerA()
viewControllerA.callback = { [weak self] _ in ... }
```

If you're using a delegate, avoid a reference cycle by using `weak var`:

```
weak var delegate: ViewControllerADelegate?
```

These styles are preferable to `NSNotificationCenter` because they're more type-safe, readable, and flexible.

Comment: Could you provide some example code using the callback property? I haven't seen it before and it would be amazing if someone who had a grasp on it already gave me an example!

Comment: I expanded it - you just declare a `var` with an optional function type, then assign it to a closure when you create the object. You can pass the object calling the callback if you want (as is done with delegate methods), or not, it matters less in this case. Add additional parameters as is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. If you can set add a rootViewController variable to your ViewControllerA and able to set it during creation of ViewControllerA then that would be the quickest way to call it.  I normally use the NSNotificationCenter when there are multiple threads involved.  So if I have an async task running , like HTTP calls, and it would require the application to react accordingly depending on the outcome the using a NSNotificationCenter is a good choice as it would easily send the message app-wide and you just need to add an observer depending on the message.

Comment: So I guess in this case using NSNotificationCenter would be a bit too much?

Comment: in your case I guess you can just add a variable to your ViewControllerA holding the reference to your rootViewController. That would be the quickest way as you only have two classes to deal with.